# why I can't change text in JLabel from public static void main?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, netbeans-7

I'm new in netbeans and java swing, but also confused. I put some JLabel's from drag and drop in netbeans with some text, and now I want to change that text from the code, and I'm getting error non-static variable can not be referred from static context.
help

```
FirstFrame f = new FirstFrame();
f.labSifra.setText("aaaa");
```

I tried this and when I start app JLabel is still with the old text

Comment: Please include an [sscce](http://www.sscce.org), otherwise this question will be closed. You've been warned! >_>

Comment: That code snippet that you've just included is not an sscce.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you try to modify your JLabel from `static void main`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
 //NetBeans GUI Init
}
```

And somewhere in your code generated from NetBeans you have:

```
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
```

If you drop for example JButton into form builder and double click it you will have method:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // Here you can change text of JLabel.
  jLabel1.setText("bla bla");
}
```

You can change defualt scope/modifier of jLabel1 by right click over GUI Component then `Properties -> Code -> Variable Modifiers`

Answer (score 1):

`main` is a *static* function, and the JLabel is a non-static member of the class, and you cannot access non-static members from a static function.

You need to delegate the setting of the text to a member function (which is non-static) of the instance of the class you've constructed in your main.

Now, if you don't understand what static and non-static mean in this context - please refer to a good book.